# Animated Scrolling Image Caption in CSS

Tags: css

I've been trying to create an AAnimated Scrolling Image Caption in CSS but i'm having a problem here!

If I set a specific height and width to the image it works like it should but if I take it out the caption shows underneath the image and it was not supposed to show. Without setting a specific height and width how do I fix it?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

figcaption {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  background: rgba(230, 150, 15, 0.6);
  transition: top 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: top 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: top 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: top 1s ease;
  -o-transition: top 1s ease;
  padding: 10px;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
  top: -43px;
}

h1,
p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6u8WDcm.jpg" alt="A Picture of a Koala Bear">
  <figcaption>
    <p>Clique na imagem para ver a galeria.</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made you an updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cj9b5h9m/1/

Believe this has the behaviour you want. There were a few changes to make, the main two being:

- position your `figure` relatively and `figcaption` absolutely with respect to the `figure`.
- give your figure `display: inline-flex` so it shrinks to fit the child image

css now looks like:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-flex;
}

figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(230, 150, 15, 0.6);
    transition: transform 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: transform 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: transform 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: transform 1s ease;
    -o-transition: transform 1s ease;
    padding: 10px;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

h1, p {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```